# Is there a way to implement Google Play in-app purchases on a website?

Tags: web-services, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am planning on connecting my app and my website and I was wondering if there was a way that users could make purchases using their google play accounts on my website?

I have had a look at the API reference [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/#Inapppurchases), but I can only see references for retrieving purchase status and various forms of cancellation. Is there a way to allow users to make in-app purchases out of app?